# How show the music album cover in 'now playing card'?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, audio, browser

I wanna show the album cover, when music playing in browser or in background (android) with html and js, like this:
How i can do that?
[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the [Media Session API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API).

```
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: "Deathcrush",
    artist: "Mayhem",
    album: "Deathcrush",
    artwork: [{src: "deathcrush.jpg"}]
  });
}
```